# apply progress bar to multiprocessing.Pool(threads).apply(function)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, progress-bar

I want to apply a progress bar for multiprocessing pool for a function that doesn't have an argument to pass. (apply progress bar to multiprocessing.Pool(threads).apply(function) )

```
accounts = []
def a():
    for account in accounts:
      while True:
         try:
             #tasks
         exept:
             continue
         break

def main():
    threads = int(input('Enter Threads: '))
    p= multiprocessing.Pool(threads)
    p.apply(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

so I want to check the progress of accounts in all the threads in one progress bar please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is not doing any sort of multithreading because the `apply` method blocks until `a` finishes processing. Moreover, `a` is processing one-by-one, successively each element of `accounts` whereas what you really want do is process the elements of `accounts` in parallel according to how many threads you have in your pool.

In the code below, function `a` now only processes a single account. The main process calls method `apply_async`, which does not block, for each element of the `accounts` list specifying a *callback* function to be invoked when `a` has finished processing and has returned a result (it implicitly returns `None`). This callback function simply advances the progress bar one unit.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import tqdm

def a(account):
    """ process account """
    import time
    # simulate doing something
    time.sleep(.5)

def update_progress_bar(result):
    # result is return code from a, which is None
    progress_bar.update(1) # one more task completed

def main():
    global progress_bar
    accounts = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    num_threads = int(input('Enter number of threads: '))
    p = ThreadPool(num_threads)
    with tqdm.tqdm(total=len(accounts)) as progress_bar:
        for account in accounts:
            p.apply_async(a, args=(account,), callback=update_progress_bar)
        # wait for all submitted tasks to complete:
        p.close()
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: - what i want actually is threading not processng ( sorry for my miss explanation)
- when a account in a() raise an expection for any reason i want to retry it untill it succeed along with all the beautiful corrections you made before

your code is very helpful and so clear ,i  learned alot from it as a beginner. thank you verymuch

Comment: Your posted question used multiprocessing in the actual code. because that is what `multiprocessing.Pool` gives you. Anyway, I have updated the question to use multithreading and the way the code is organized is the way it needs to be to concurrently process the accounts, otherwise what is the point of creating a thread pool? That is, function `a` processes a single account, which is the argument passed to it. Feel free to add back any error handling and retry logic. It's not as if you had any real error handling to begin with.